# Traefik can't proxy to internal docker

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to setup Traefik so that when I hit mydomain.com, it will proxy the call to an internal docker container, but I'm so far unable to make it work. The internal container `admin-webui` contains an HTML page hosted via nginx and exposed to port 4200. This is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  ingress:
    # redacted
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
        # redacted certificates
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable: true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints: websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`mydomain.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service: api@internal
    networks:
      - inbound
  admin_webui:
    #redacted
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.service=admin_webui
      - traefik.http.services.admin_webui.loadbalancer.server.port=4200
      - traefik.docker.network=inbound
    networks:
      - inbound

networks:
  inbound:
    driver: bridge
```

The service is discovered fine, here's a screenshot of what the service looks like:
[image]

Now if I exec inside the docker container for traefik, and I `curl 172.20.0.3` I get the correct response, so the network looks like is working fine. I cannot access the internal dashboard via mydomain.com/dashboard, but I can do so using IP_ADDRESS:8080/dashboard. Beats me why traefik won't proxy, anybody able to help? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing all the labels from the ingress service by editing the labels in the admin_webui as follow:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.entrypoints=web-secure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.admin_webui.service=admin_webui"
  - "traefik.http.services.admin_webui.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
  - "traefik.docker.network=inbound"
```